# Which zookeeper handle to use?

Tags: c, apache-zookeeper

I am a newbie in ZooKeeper.

```
static zhandle_t *zh;

static void data_watcher(zhandle_t *wzh, int type, int state, const char * zpath, void *watcher_ctx)
{
    char *zoo_data = malloc(ZDATALEN * sizeof(char));
    int zoo_data_len = ZDATALEN;

    if (state == ZOO_CONNECTED_STATE)
    {
        if (type == ZOO_CHANGED_EVENT)
        {
            // Which zh to use here? wzh or zh?
            zoo_wget(wzh, zoo_path, data_watcher, (void *)watcher_ctx, zoo_data, &zoo_data_len, NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "!!! Data Change Detected\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", zoo_data);
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
   zh = zookeeper_init(host_port, connection_watcher, 2000, 0, 0, 0);
   ...
   zoo_wget(zh, zoo_path, data_watcher, watcher_ctx, zdata_buf, &zdata_len, NULL)
}
```

As shown above, what I am puzzled here is that which zookeeper handle to use in the watcher callback function?And why? Many thanks for your time.